# Can't find some Akka libs in Eclips

Tags: scala, akka

I have recently started exploring Scala.
I have installed Eclips and I integrated Akka-Actors Libs in the Build-Path Project.

But whenever I try compiling the project, I got an erorr. I can't resolve such libraries.

```
import akka.routing.{Routing, CyclicIterator}
import Routing._
```

Any idea how to configure Akka to work perfectly with Eclips ?

Comment: What version of Akka are you using? (How is anybody going to be able yo answer if you don't give us this information?)

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT, there's no such class in Akka.
Router, yes - Routing, no.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I have Added the **akka-actor_2.10-2.3.0.jar** and the ***config-1.0.2.jar*** libraries but the error persists.

In the webpage of akka (akka.io) they use both imports in a example proyect.
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/1.3/intro/getting-started-first-scala.html

```
 package akka.tutorial.first.scala

    import akka.actor.{Actor, PoisonPill}
    import Actor._
    import akka.routing.{Routing, CyclicIterator}
    import Routing._
     .....
    .....
    ....
```

**ANSWER:** You should use spray and the spray's library, it has a routing method you can use aswell.

```
import spray.routing._
```

You have to download the **spray-routing-1.2.0.jar** if you want to use it (http://repo.spray.io/io/spray/spray-routing/)